# VS Code No Quick Fix for Generating TypeScript Interface Methods

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ide, code-generation

Before today, I was able to use the *quick fix* option to generate methods on a class that implements a given interface. I would simply begin the class definition; something like:

```js
export default class MyService extends BaseService implements IMyService {

}
```

Then I would hover over the class name (i.e. `MyService`).

There would be a red squiggly line under the class name, because the members of the interface (i.e. `IMyService`) had not been implemented. After hovering a moment, the quick fix menu would pop-up and I could select an option to generate the members.

Today, everything is working as before, except when the quick fix menu pops-up it states: **No quick fixes available**, even though it states the members that should be added to the class to correct the error.

[image: inspecting typescript class issue]

I've disable all my plug-ins and have restarted the application, but the issue persists.

The interface I'm currently working with is composed of 4 **required** methods. The base class my class is extending has no conflicting members with the interface, and the problem persists when I remove the `extends` clause.

How can I fix this? Is there something I'm doing to cause this?

Answer (score 2):

**Missing Dependencies**

The problem was, my interface required the `Request` and `Response` modules from the `express` package. Once I imported them into the class file I was able to use the *quick fix*.

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
```